# How can I implement code into an Alexa Skill?

Tags: javascript, python, json, alexa-skills-kit

I'm running into significant problems understanding how to turn my Python or JS code into a skill for Alexa. I have code written in Python and half written in JS, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to implement it into an Alexa skill.

I've looked through so many tutorials, examples, and walkthroughs now that I'm starting to think that Alexa can't run a short code to determine her response. It seems like every single tutorial is for a facts skill which pulls from an API, which is not what I'm looking to do. At least, I don't think so - I'm still learning.

I've written the code itself in VSCode, but I've been putting as much of the skill together in Amazon Developer Panel as possible, but I'm to a point where I need to calculate how many days have passed since the start date, get the modelo, and output the chores on the revolving four-day list. So far as I can tell, that isn't something I can do without writing a function or two, but everything seems to be a class in JSON. Is that all Alexa uses?

I feel like I've somehow missed something really important in my education so far, or perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding Alexa skills, but I desperately need help to make sense of this.

For Example, if I have this portion of the JSON code:

```
    const ChoresIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
        && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'ChoresIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const speakOutput = 'Oh, you know. Stuff.';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
        .getResponse();
}
    };
```

Say I want to implement this code:

```
    var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    const measure_from = new Date('2022-04-08');
    const today = new Date();
    const diff_in_days = Math.floor((today - measure_from) / one_day) - 1 ;
```

Where on earth do I put it?

Thank you in advance. I've been trying to figure this out for over a month and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: That's not JSON code, but anyway, those kind of calculations are the things could be done in the API that you're not keen on setting up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer:

**Anywhere really, it just depends on your logic**.

In that case, if you want this part of code to run after the `ChoresIntent` is invoked, then within the handle function.

### Long answer:

[This is the official tutorial](https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-zero-to-hero) you will need to understand how to build an alexa skill from scratch and will cover 99% of your actual & future questions

Regarding your question, you need to understand that this is how Alexa SDK is designed:

- One Intent = One user interaction
- One Intent has 2 function:

  - canHandle, a simple condition from the request to determine if it should call the handle function
  - handle, the function executed if it matches the canHandle function.

You also have the possibility to run a piece of code after each request. You have what is called `interceptors`, that allow you to execute code just after receiving the response (to allow your intent to have data fetch from a database) or you can do it before replying the request to the user, after the intent.

**In any case, I recommend you to follow the tutorial carefully, it will explain how you can create a skill on Alexa, but it will not teach you the basic of JS or Python required.**